# Save microsoft excel chart as jpg

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to save bar chart from Microsoft Excel 2010 for using as jpg.

Is there a way for saving it?

Comment: Say more about your environment.  Are you trying to do this in an external application?  Or in a macro in Excel?  Or within Excel itself?

Comment: I want to save from Excel.

Comment: In VBA charts have an Export() method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select the graph, hit copy (ctrl+c or right click and select copy) and then paste into paint (or any image editing software) to save in the correct format.

Comment: Is there any better way than that?

Comment: Also, selecting "Home/Clipboard/Copy->Copy As Picture" will give you the option of copying as-printed or as-shown-on-screen.  The "on screen" option (suprisingly) appears to give a much higher resolution, if that is helpful...

Comment: No, there is no native option to save a graph as a picture - which seems like an oversight in my opinion.

Comment: @unfrev - from VBA you can use the chart's `Export()` method. It allows you to specify which format to use.

Answer (score 7):

As @TimWilliams noted in the comments, charts have an Export method in VBA.  Here's a sample macro that will save the active chart as an image file in your workbook's directory.

The file type has been changed from the JPG you requested to PNG, which is a better image file format for line art like Excel charts. JPG is optimized for photographic images.

```
Sub savechart()
    ActiveChart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\yourchart.png", Filtername:="PNG"
End Sub
```

Comment: Good suggestion about PNG format instead of JPG.

Answer (score 0):

Office 2010:
Select the Chart and **Copy** the chart from Excel;
**Paste Special** as JPEG into Word;
Right Click on picture in Word and select **Save As Picture**. 
Job done